# How to install ubuntu 16.04 with the same live media drivers and config

Tags: nvidia, dell, intel

How can I install ubuntu 16.04 with the same drivers as the Live installation media?

The live media works ok in my inspiron 7559. Ethernet works fine as well as the display.
After installation, I can't boot to the desktop at all. And for sopme reason I can't access the F1-F4 terminals either and ethernet isn't working at all.